# Knockout with jquery mobile in Cefsharp

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm facing an issue in knock out js,

I'm binding the options of the select control from an observabale array,

If the number of options are more, if I click on the select option, jquery mobile design gets hanged.

I'm using cefsharp form loading chrome page inside cefsharp,

The thing is the select feature works fine in chrome browser but not inside cefsharp,

I'm binding to the select control as follows,

Html,

```
<select name ="name" id = "name" data-bind ="options:namevalues">
```

Javascript,

```
<script>
 function viewmodel()
  {
  var self=this;
  self.namevalues = ko.observablearray(['abc','bcd']);
  //many name values, say 20, it gets hanged inside cefsharp but works fine in chrome,     no error console messages
   }
```

Could someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the chrome dev tools?? It would enable to use breakpoints etc etc - a sane development experience.

in cefSettings:

> PackLoadingDisabled=false

then (after the browserInitialised evennt has fired) call

> _browser.ShowDevTools();

make sure you ship the 'pak' file in the bin dir (latest nuget version of cefSharp should take care of this in the targets)

then you should see another window open with the dev tools.

Hopefully that'll help diagnose your issue.
I've tried knockout and angular in there and both worked out fine (although angular needed some awkward route work)